# In python, when argument data type are NaN, how to return an NaN, not an TypeError

Tags: python, nan

e.g. I defined an function which needs several input arguments, if some keyword arguments not being assigned, typically there be an TypeError message, but I want to change it, to output an NaN as the result, could it be done?

```
def myfunc( S0, K ,r....):
    if  S0 = NaN or .....:
```

How to do it?
Much appreciated.

Edited:

```
def myfunc(a):
    return a / 2.5 + 5

print myfunc('whatever')

>python -u "bisectnewton.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bisectnewton.py", line 6, in <module>
    print myfunc('whatever')
  File "bisectnewton.py", line 4, in myfunc
    return a / 2.5 + 5
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'float'
>Exit code: 1
```

What I want is, the myfunc(a) only accpets an number as the input, if some other data type  like a string = 'whatever' inputed, I don't want to just output an default error message, I want it to output something like return 'NaN' to tell others that the input should be an number.

Now I changed it to this, but still not working, 
btw, is none the same as NaN? I think they're different.

```
def myfunc(S0):
    if math.isnan(S0):
        return 'NaN'
    return a / 2.5 + 5

print myfunc('whatever')

>python -u "bisectnewton.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bisectnewton.py", line 8, in <module>
    print myfunc('whatever')
  File "bisectnewton.py", line 4, in myfunc
    if math.isnan(S0):
TypeError: a float is required
>Exit code: 1
```

Thanks!

Comment: After answering, I realized that your question isn't completely clear. Could you provide a short (5-10 lines should be enough), complete program that runs and demonstrates the error you are seeing? Consider the guidelines in http://SSCCE.ORG for how to generate the program.

Comment: Use `math.isnan` function to check if `S0` is a `NaN`.

Comment: No, `None` is not the same as NaN.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can capture the TypeError and do whatever you want with it:

```
def myfunc(a):
  try:
    return a / 2.5 + 5
  except TypeError:
    return float('nan')

print myfunc('whatever')
```

[The Python Tutorial](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html) has an excellent chapter on this subject.

Comment: Thanks, it works! but it seems that whatever kind of typeError it will return a NaN, what if it's not because that the input data type is wrong, but due to other typeErrors? also, the tutorial is good!

Answer (score 0):

```
def myfunc(S0 = None, K = None, r = None, ....):
    if S0 is None or K is None or r is None:
        return NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, to generate a NaN you do `float('nan')`:

```
>>> import math
>> float('nan')
nan
>>> math.isnan(float('nan'))
True
```

So you can `return float('nan')` wherever you want to return the `nan`. I recommend you just raise the exception, though.

Comment: thanks, I prefer to raise the exception, too. Just the assignment requires so, and I will definitely ask my professor.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use TypeError, then how about using AttributeError?

```
def myfunc(a):
  try:
    return a / 2.5 + 5
  except AttributeError:
    return float('nan')

print myfunc('whatever')
```